# Adding background blur via CSS behind pop-up modal

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to blur the overall 100% background behind a fixed modal that pops up on a button click.

I'd have thought it'd just be a blur filter, but it seems to only cover a small portion of the screen. I've tried adding 100vh height + width, and setting the position as fixed with top: 0, left: 0 but the elements aren't centering right.

To be clear - I'm wanting the background elements behind the modal to be blurred, so the section behind it but the modal in focus.

Here's the HTML (not sure much point but posting anyway):

That's all I've coded so far - want to do this before adding the rest in. Any tips would be great. Cheers!

```css
.blog-modal-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.blog-modal-container {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog-modal-section">
  <div class="blog-modal-container">
    <div class="blog-modal-content">
      <h2>My blogs</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Blog 1 - Coming Soon</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But where is your modal? Your question is not clear.

Comment: The modal is centred in the middle of the screen. That's the point of the modal - and the display flex, with align-items and justify-content set as centre. The modal section covers the whole viewport, the modal container contains the actual contents of the modal. I want the modal section to blur the background, but have 0 opacity. I can't set it.

Comment: Sorry, think I explained it wrong - imagine the modal section covers the whole viewport. The contents behind it (i.e. rest of the webpage) is visible behind it, like it's see-through, but it's blurred. The modal container is centred dead central in the middle of the modal section. That is completely visible, and not blurred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following would make a screen-filling element that also adds blur.

```
.bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
```

Comment: this casues massive performance drop for modal content updates and huge hardware usage, at least in my case

Comment: @ErfanAzary  For this blur, the average of its surrounding pixels is calculated for every pixel. So a bigger radius requires a lot more calculations than a small radius. So if you pick 3 or 5px, it should a lot faster. That shouldn't make any midrange 2015-era graphics card or any phone that was sold since 2018 sweat at all.